I don't understand how energy is conserved when an electron-positron pair decay into a muon-antimuon pair
I'm trying to self-study particle physics using Griffiths Introduction to Elementary Particles, and when doing exercise 2.7 I'm getting this portion of the question wrong. Given that the problem doesn't tell me when the particles are at rest and when Kinetic Energy is involved, I'm using the particles' rest mass when calculating energy. This worked when calculating the energy for a sigma 0 particle decaying into a lambda 0 and pion 0 but it did not work for the electron-positron pair annihilation. So I am confused about when to use rest mass, when to add kinetic energy, and how to determine the value of the kinetic energy if the problem doesn't tell me.
EDIT: I realized I misunderstood the question. Eventually, I realized that the question was merely asking if there EXISTS a possible decay where the particle has enough kinetic energy to decay into the resulting particles, rather than asking whether the given reaction, being treated as a SPECIFIC reaction, is possible or not based on the information given.

Welcome to Physics SE!  Please don't include profanity in your username, as that could get your post flagged.

There is a big difference between two particles annihilating and one particle decaying though. Is the position also at rest in the electrons rest frame?

@Triatticus Yes ofc, but I still don't know when to add kinetic energy and how much I should add if it's not given to me. Should I always add kinetic energy if it's two particles annihilating? That would make sense to me, but then how can I find the amount of kinetic energy if I'm not given any info? Sorry if it's a very simple question I'm new to this

The thing I was trying to get at there is that you can use special frames like the center of mass frame to help you with your calculations. You should review using this information and conservation of four-momentum to make your life easier.

The electron and positron each with mass m and momentum p  may collide to produce a muon of mass M and an antimuon both at rest, no? Nondimensionalizing c=1,
$$
E_{TOT}^2/4=m^2+p^2=M^2.
$$
You might need to review basic relativistic kinematics, Ch 3, Fig. 3.6(b), the very essence of particle pair creation. (You could think of a muon-antimuon pair at rest decaying to an electron-positron pair.) I have simplified the problem for you by taking the muon/antimuon momenta, p', to vanish in the cm frame, so p above is uniquely defined.

Thanks, I knew about 4-momentum conservation, I just didn't understand the question was asking whether the given reaction could occur if the conditions are right. But your question made me realize it was a general question and not a specific one.
